# (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, base-de-datos

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial en el que se realiza una clave foreana, a la hora de ejecutar el programa en la cmd me arroja el error de (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: empresa
[SQL: INSERT INTO empresa (nombre, fundacion) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Google', 1998)].

Este es el codigo:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='sqlite:///C:\\Users\\Dell\\PycharmProjects\\db.testfive'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

lenguajes_programador = db.Table('lenguajes_programador',

                            db.Column('lenguaje_id', db.Integer,    
                                                 db.ForeignKey('lenguaje.id'),primary_key=True),
                            
                            db.Column('programador_id', db.Integer, 
                            db.ForeignKey('programador.id'), primary_key=True))

class Empresa(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(20))
    fundacion = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'

class Lenguaje(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(60))
    creador = db.Column(db.String(60))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'


class Programador(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(30))
    edad = db.Column(db.Integer)

    #llave -- clave foreana

    empresa_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('empresa.id'))

    #relacion entre la columna y el objeto

    empresa = db.relationship('Empresa', backref=db.backref('programadores', lazy=True))
    lenguajes = db.relationship('Lenguaje', secondary=lenguajes_programador,
                                backref=db.backref('programadores', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
       return f'{self.nombre}'
```

Y aqui se crea la base de datos y unas instancias en la consola para estudiar una consultas.

```
db.create_all()

google = Empresa(nombre='Google', fundacion=1998)

microsoft = Empresa(nombre='Microsoft', fundacion=1975)

db.session.add(google)

db.session.add(microsoft)

java = Lenguaje(nombre='Java', creador='James Gosling')

c = Lenguaje(nombre='C', creador='Dennis Ritchie')

db.session.add(java)

db.session.add(c)

juanito = Programador(nombre='Maria', edad=23, empresa=google)

mark = Programador(nombre='Mark', edad=26, empresa=microsoft)

db.session.add(mark)

db.session.add(juanito)

db.session.commit()
```

Y me arroja el error a la hora de poner el commit.

Answer (score 0):

en vez de usar :

```
def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'
```

usa **init** que es el método por defecto para instanciar la clase:

```
def __init__(self,id,nombre,fundacion):
  self.id = id
  self.nombre = nombre
  self.fundacion = fundacion
```

en la clase que tienes los modelos yo meterían un :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.create_all()
```

o poner el db.create_all() justo despues de la creación de los modelos.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Que pro, de verdad me ayudo muchas gracias.